# jquery image scroller

Tags: jquery

I'm making an image scroller with jQuery but I'm having a little trouble.

I've almost got it, but for some strange reason the last slide scrolls past before the image slider starts. Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BAEtV/

and you'll see what the problem is.

I can't understand why this is happening, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed

```
var start = 0;
```

to

```
var start = 1;
```

and it seems to be working